# Creating a new map from existing maps in python

Tags: python, pandas

This question might be common but I am new to python and would like to learn more from the community. I have 2 map files which have data mapping like this:
map1 : A --> B
map2 : B --> C,D,E

I want to create a new map file which will be A --> C

What is the most efficient way to achieve this in python? A generic approach would be very helpful as I need to apply the same logic on different files and different columns

Example:

Map1:

```
1,100
2,453
3,200
```

Map2:

```
100,25,30,
200,300,,
250,190,20,1
```

My map3 should be:

```
1,25
2,0
3,300
```

As `453` is not present in map2, our map3 contains value `0` for key `2`.

Comment: what is output if `4,190` and `5,30` in `Map1` ?

Comment: Are important values `,30,` and `,20,1` in `Map2` ?

Comment: if ```4,190``` and ```5,30``` are present in map1. map3 will have:
```4,0``` and ```5,0```,
as ```190``` and ```30``` are not the primary keys in map2.

Also as I mentioned, map2 data format is B --> C,D,E

Answer (score 0):

First create DataFrames:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(Map1, header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv(Map2, header=None)
```

And then use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by second column with by Series created by `df2` with set index by first column, last replace missing values to `0` for not matched values:

```
df1[1] = df1[1].map(df2.set_index(0)[1]).fillna(0, downcast='int')
print (df1)
   0    1
0  1   25
1  2    0
2  3  300
```

EDIT: for mapping multiple columns use left join with remove only missing columns by [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and columns `b,c` used for join, last replace missing values:

```
df1.columns=['a','b']
df2.columns=['c','d','e','f']

df = (df1.merge(df2, how='left', left_on='b', right_on='c')
         .dropna(how='all', axis=1)
         .drop(['b','c'], axis=1)
         .fillna(0)
         .convert_dtypes())
print (df)
   a    d   e
0  1   25  30
1  2    0   0
2  3  300   0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just a follow-up. If I want to create a mapping of ```A -->C,E```, what should I change in the above code?

Comment: @AbhayKrSomani - what means `A -->C,E` ? It means in ouput `1;25,30` ? Or something else?

Comment: Sorry, I meant ```A --> C,D```. map3 output for the same set of data would be: ```1,25,30```, ```2,0,0``` and ```3,300,0```

Comment: @AbhayKrSomani - Answer was edited.